# C# how to specify a datetime in UTC

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a asp.net `webapi` endpoint which accepts a date parameter in UTC. To test that i want to specify a `datetime` in UTC. Can anyone help me how to create  `datetime` value as UTC date? I am trying the following:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(2016, 09, 04, 09, 00, 00, DateTimeKind.Utc).ToString()
```

Not sure whether this is correct.

Comment: Try th following

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc (youdategoeshere)
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc (youdategoeshere, Timezone)


This is an overload, so you if you have a timezone source you the second overload.

Comment: @user1010863 i couldn't find anything in your comment to try

Comment: @user1010863 yes i got it. i will try. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`var dateTime = new DateTime(2016, 09, 04, 09, 00, 00).ToString("r");`

This will result in

`Sun, 04 Sep 2016 09:00:00 GMT`